# subqueries inside laravel raw syntax

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to use `DB::raw('raw sql query')` to run the query below:

```
    $rates = DB::raw('SELECT
           mid,
           x.qty_t/x.qty_total,
           x.qty_t,
           x.qty_total,
           FROM
              (SELECT
                 mid,
                 SUM(CASE WHEN (mtc="qty") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty_total,
                 SUM(CASE WHEN (mtc="qty") THEN rte ELSE 0 END) AS qty_t,
                 STDDEV(CASE WHEN (mtc="qty") THEN rte ELSE 0 END) AS qty_sd
            FROM
               t_r
            GROUP BY
               mid) x')->get();
```

I'm getting a syntax error after `(SELECT` on `mid`, `mtc` and `t_r`.

How can I get this to work using `raw`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap DB::select around it. Something like this should work.

```
$rates = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT
       mid,
       x.qty_t/x.qty_total,
       x.qty_stddev,
       x.qty_total,
       FROM
          (SELECT
             mid,
             SUM(CASE WHEN (mtc="qty") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qty_total,
             SUM(CASE WHEN (mtc="qty") THEN rte ELSE 0 END) AS qty_t,
             STDDEV(CASE WHEN (mtc="qty") THEN rte ELSE 0 END) AS qty_sd
        FROM
           t_r
        GROUP BY
           mid) x'))->get();
```